# Hide Forget Password button on Amplify Authenticator

Tags: aws-amplify

I've successfully disabled the signup form setting this piece of code

```
<amplify-authenticator [hideSignUp]="true"> 
  <ng-template amplifySlot="authenticated" let-user="user" let-signOut="signOut">

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </ng-template>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

But now I wish to hide the Forgot Password button... is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty slot for the **sign-in-footer** to hide the forgot password button.

```html
<amplify-authenticator [hideSignUp]="true"> 
    <ng-template amplifySlot="sign-in-footer">
        <div></div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template amplifySlot="authenticated" let-user="user" let-signOut="signOut">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ng-template>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Basically, you can customize the header and footer of each form. You can read more about it [here](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator?platform=angular#headers--footers).